# How to add git server's cryptographic algorithms to my git/ssh installation?

Tags: windows, git, github, putty, pageant

The error I get ever since [GitHub removed outdated/insecure algorithms](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-23-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed/):

```
FATAL ERROR: Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521)

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I suppose I need to install or enable or add one of the available algorithms on my machine.

But how to do that? Where are the settings for algorithms? All non-github repositories work just fine for me.

I use putty/pageant on Windows 7.

Comment: @Chris GitHub also removed insecure ciphers from their SSH configuration, not just HTTPS.  https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: Right you are, @EdwardThomson. I'm not sure how I missed that in the announcement. I'd still like to know what Git client the OP is using, though.